# How to add multiple filters on Server Audit of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, filter, audit, audit-logging

I want to filter SQL Audits so that I do not want to capture events triggered by certain users and certain schema. In one of the existing Server Audit, I found the filter predicate as

```
(
[schema_name]<>'sys' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Distributor' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Replicator' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Merger' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Collecter' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Reporter' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Starter' AND 
)
```

I think it should be `OR` and not `AND`. As per TSQL, it looks like above condition will never be satisfied. `AND` means all of the conditions **must** be satisfied. I did read the logs using function `sys.fn_get_audit_file` and did not see any records belonging to above restricted users and schema. It looked like above predicate worked though.

Is `AND` here acting like a separator of the rules.

Could you please explain this?

Comment: It you prefer `or` then the predicate should be `NOT ([schema_name] = 'sys' OR 
[server_principal_name] = 'SILVER\Distributor' /*more*/)`

Comment: Sorry @AlexKudryashev. I did not understand. I do not want to capture from `sys` schema and I do not want to capture events from all above users.

Comment: Predicates `a<>b and c<>d` and `not (a=b or c=d)` are equivalent.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev You made things so clear. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your predicate

```
(
[schema_name]<>'sys' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Distributor' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Replicator' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Merger' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Collecter' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Reporter' AND 
[server_principal_name]<>'SILVER\Starter' AND 
)
```

to its equivalent which uses `or`

```
NOT (
[schema_name] = 'sys' OR 
[server_principal_name] = 'SILVER\Distributor' OR 
[server_principal_name] = 'SILVER\Replicator' OR 
[server_principal_name] = 'SILVER\Merger' OR 
[server_principal_name] = 'SILVER\Collecter' OR 
[server_principal_name] = 'SILVER\Reporter' OR 
[server_principal_name] = 'SILVER\Starter'  
)
```

or even better readable

```
[schema_name]<>'sys' AND 
[server_principal_name] NOT IN (
'SILVER\Distributor',
'SILVER\Replicator', 
'SILVER\Merger',
'SILVER\Collecter',
'SILVER\Reporter',
'SILVER\Starter' 
)
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when using NOT IN with SQL 2012.

Comment: is there any way that we can compare two values? 
suppose
if ([schema_name] = 'sys' and [server_principal_name] = 'Tahir')
then this will filter out the data while remaining other conditions also exists.